# Deserialize a value which can be an array or atomic

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using Gson and want to deserialize the following JSON alternatives into the same class `Values`. In the latter case I would like to receive a `List` of just one element. Is there a way to accomplish this in Gson without having to write a custom deserializer?

```
//Array:
{
  "Value": [205.4, 13.5]
}

//Single value:
{
  "Value": 205.4
}
```

Deserialize both into:

```
public static class Values {
      private List<Double> Value;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42318301/166589

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BornToCode mentioned the solution is to write a custom `TypeAdapter` and register it with the `GsonBuilder`:

```
public class ListTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<List<Double>> {

  @Override
  public void write(final JsonWriter writer, final List<Double> doubles) throws IOException {
    writer.beginArray();
    for (final double value : doubles) {
      writer.value(value);
    }
    writer.endArray();
  }

  @Override
  public List<Double> read(final JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    final List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<>();

    if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
      reader.beginArray();
      while (reader.hasNext()) {
        doubles.add(reader.nextDouble());
      }
      reader.endArray();
    } else {
      doubles.add(reader.nextDouble());
    }
    return doubles;
  }
}
```

Register it:

```
GSONBUILDER.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<List<Double>>(){}.getType(), 
    new ListTypeAdapter().nullSafe());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in Gson unless using custom `TypeAdapter`.

```
public class AwesomeType extends ArrayList<Double> {
    ...
}

public class AwesomeTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<AwesomeType> {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, AwesomeType value) throws IOException {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public AwesomeType read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        AwesomeType result = new AwesomeType();
        if (in.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
            in.beginArray();
            while (in.peek() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY)
                result.add(in.nextDouble());
            in.endArray();
        } else {
            result.add(in.nextDouble());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Register this type adapter to your Gson and use this class in your model instead of `List<Double>`.