# Handle retrofit 2 response object with a field with type String or type Array

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I am trying to retrieve list of items using an api. The api is designed so that in the list of items, a field in one item is a String and the same field in another item is an Array. If I declare the field as an Array, retrofit throws an error because in some cases it returns String. How can I use one field for two situations. I tried declaring it as an Object and than casting it to the appropriate List of objects but it throws an exception because in this case the type is List of LinkedTreeMap. I am using Gson for deserialization.

Example:

```
{
    [
        {
            "field": ""
        },
        {
            "field": [{},{},{}]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: ask your web api developer to change the structure of api. Use list of object in both the cases

Comment: @Shubham is right: if possible, ask for making the API consistent. If the API cannot be changed for whatever reason, you might be interested in a similar question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42314056/how-to-convert-dynamic-json-reponse-with-java-gson-library/42318301#42318301

Comment: @Shubham The api can't be changed since it is a third party api.

Comment: @RobertMarkovski Your JSON is actually malformed (syntax issues due to probably lost JSON structure while editing/posting the question). Another thing is that Gson, by default, uses `ArrayList` to parse JSON arrays, so casting it to `List` is fully legit in this case. But if you're getting `LinkedTreeMap`, then you must have a wrong mapping: Gson uses `LinkedTreeMap`s in order to deserialize JSON objects, so such type casting is illegal. Just make sure your mappings are correct.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv The problem is that I don't know what mapping to use. The api is not consistent. If there is data for the field it will return list of objects but when there is no data it returns empty strings instead of empty list. So if I try to map it with List<SomeObject> it crashes because some item will return empty string.

Comment: @RobertMarkovski I mean that Gson creates `LinkedTreeMap` (if you expect an `Object`) because your mapping points to a JSON object in your JSON where you think a JSON array should be located at. To me it looks like you have something like this: `class Response{Object mapping;}`, `{"mapping": {...}}`, and then `List list = (List) response.mapping;` -- this is where illegal type cast between `List` and `LinkedTreeMap` can happen.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a custom deserializer and react to any field based on any conditions, un your object that field could be of type "Any" but you may be loosing the point of map to an Object.

[Here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/retrofit-an-gson-deserialize-a-specific-object-type-based-on-the-value-of-a-field/10440/3) you can find some examples